How 'fundamental' is position?
From my knowledge, which is admittedly inadequate, it seems that in Classical Mechanics and other parts of physics, the integral of position isn't used at all. As in, one can easily imagine scenarios where velocity, acceleration, jerk, or further derivatives of position are necessary to calculate the future state of a system.
Is there a certain system wherein the integral of position, the thing whose derivative would give displacement, is necessary to calculate the future state of a system?
If not, why is it position that is required to calculate the future state of a system, and not velocity (which is also needed for CM), or position's integral, or anything else?
The following is an edit, as the comments show that I was very unclear. (Sorry, I haven't learnt much so my question may be based off of various wrong things)
Both position and velocity are required in Classical mechanics to calculate future states. Acceleration and further derivatives can be worked out from these two.
Is there a reason why it is these two which are necessary for calculating future states, and not some other values such as the integral of the position? Is here a reason that the antiderivative of the position is never needed in classical mechanics to predict future states?

There is something I do not understand in your question. According to Classical Mechanics, the future state doesn't depend only on the position but also on velocity. Why do you exclude velocity?

For most purposes, position and velocity are sufficient to figure out the classical evolution. There is simply no need to consider the time integral of position.

Have you studied projectile motion yet? Knowing position and velocity at one time lets you figure out position and velocity at later times. This is because $\mathbf r(t)$ satisfies a second-order differential equation. The same applies to the Solar System and lots of other systems where forces do not depend on anything other than position and velocity.

Hell, have you studied the simple harmonic oscillator?

Well, everywhere you go, there you are.

The integral of the position can be interpreted as some kind of center of mass of the trajectory, right? Or do you have another interpretation?

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Sorry, I made a mistake as I am not learned in this. as Ghoster says, position and velocity are sufficient to figure out classical evolution. My question was why only these two values? Why it is that acceleration isn't as necessary and fundamental, or position?

@CosmasZachos No, I have not, please do tell me on how it helps? Thanks!

@Ghoster Why is it that 'there is simply no need to consider the time integral of position'? As for your second comment, I understand that a second-order differential equation would require two values be specified, such as position and velocity. But why not the integral of the position and the position? Why are these two values in particular, necessary? Thanks!

I'm voting to reopen as this question is sufficiently clear to me.

The point is twofold.
In classical mechanics
(1) the fundamental equation to find the motion law $x=x(t)$ for a material point subjected to external inteactions is
$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=F$$
(2) the force $F$ describing interactions at time $t$ turns out to be a function of $t, x(t)$ and the velocity $v(t)= \frac{dx}{dt}$ at the same time $t$.
The arising differential equation
$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=F(t,x(t), \frac{dx}{dt}(t))$$
admits a unique solution once one gives $x(0)$ and $v(0)= \frac{dx}{dt}|_{t=0}.$
The physical issue is why the forces at time $t$ are functions of $x(t)$ and $v(t)$ (same time!) and only of these kinematical variables?
I do not have an answer, but I remark that actually this  framework is only an approximation. It holds for (1) small velocities (compared with the light velocity), (2) neglecting self interactions, and (3) disregarding quantum phenomena.

Thank you very much! Could you explain just a bit on your final paragraph? Are there then examples of situations which don't require these two but others, in Quantum Mechanics or Relativity or 'self interactions'?

Was the "I do not have an answer" in the sense of philosophically that it is unclear why the universe should be stable or is the Ostrogradsky instability unknown to you or am I just missing something entirely?
